# replacing text of links with jquery

Tags: jquery, string, replace, indexof

i'm trying to loop through divs which has specific string to replace it with another one
inside html i have divs with class "meta" some of them contain word like facebook twitter and they are links and i want to replace only the word facebook with a space to delete it and keep the link of twitter as it is so i'm using this code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".meta").each(function() {
    var newstring = $(this).text();
    if(newstring.indexOf('facebook') >= 0){
      news = newstring.replace('facebook','');
    }
    $(this).html(news);
  });
});
```

but the the twitter appears as just text not a link and when using

```
var newstring = $(this).html();
```

nothing happens it doesn't replace the string any help please

Thakns in advance

Comment: You want to delete the *word* `Facebook` from the link? Or you want to delete the link itself? What HTML are you starting with, and what do you want it to become?

Comment: Most likely the element has more than just text inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
​$("a:contains('facebook')").remove();​
```

Comment: works great thanks alot just changed it to this
$("a:contains('facebook')").each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

Comment: @jqbeginner, that's overhead. jQuery functions are chainable for this reason

Comment: Adding `.each()` is pointless in this case, you shouldn't do it unless there's more to perform than just `$(this).remove()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`:

```
$(this).text(news);
```